# Error: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, routes

Im trying to make a basic web scraper with Rails. everytime I hit the scrape button it sends me to the correct location but gives me this error everytime.

here is my `restaurants_controller.rb`  file

```
  def scrape
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g31892-Rogers_Arkansas.html'
    response = RestaurantsScraper.process(url)
    if response[:status] == :completed && response[:error].nil?
      flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully scraped url"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = response[:error]
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error: #{e}"
  end
```

Here is my `restaurantscrapper.rb` file

```
class RestaurantsScraper < Kimurai::Base
    @name = 'restaurants_scraper'
    @engine = :mechanize


    def self.process(url)
        @start_url = [url]
        self.crawl!
    end


    def parse(response, url, data:{})
        response.xpath("//div[@class=_1llCuDZj]").each do |t|
            item = {}
            
            item[:title] = t.css('a._15_ydu6b')&.text&.squish&.gsub('[^0-9].', '')
            item[:type] = t.css('span._1p0FLy4t')&.text&.squish
            item[:reviews] = t.css('span.w726Ki5B').text&.squish
            item[:top_reviews] = t.css('a._2uEVo25r _3mPt7dFq').text&.squish

            Restaurant.where(item).first_or_create
        end
    end

end
```

Here is a picture of the error im getting
[image: Error]

Here is the error in the console

```
Processing by RestaurantsController#scrape as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3qXvtTOsU6VVtxaPvNXyCjpdnHLOgCvFgQYzB1JnhoHDz8ySF6gK/n5x+/XW5HC0HwfzQ1bFCu/KCfF3nA1SIQ=="}
I, [2021-01-26 02:35:35 -0600#218] [C: 14760]  INFO -- restaurants_scraper: Spider: started: restaurants_scraper
F, [2021-01-26 02:35:35 -0600#218] [C: 14760] FATAL -- restaurants_scraper: Spider: stopped: {:spider_name=>"restaurants_scraper", :status=>:failed, :error=>"#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)>", :environment=>"development", :start_time=>2021-01-26 02:35:35.6330106 -0600, :stop_time=>2021-01-26 02:35:35.6336933 -0600, :running_time=>"0s", :visits=>{:requests=>0, :responses=>0}, :items=>{:sent=>0, :processed=>0}, :events=>{:requests_errors=>{}, :drop_items_errors=>{}, :custom=>{}}}
  Rendering restaurants/scrape.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered restaurants/scrape.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 41)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 41.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4104)
```

Comment: What line and file is the error coming from? Check your console output and it will tell you on the line below the error.

Comment: I edited the post to add the error. Still confused.

Comment: Can you post signature of `crawl` method in `RestaurantsScraper`. It might be expecting two arguments.

Comment: @PenoG I think the `parse` method required a `url:` in arguments: https://github.com/augustoam/kimurai#minimum-required-crawler-structure 
Also, it should be `@start_urls` (plural). Not quite sure if it's the issue. But try to put logs or use debugger

Comment: Im using Kimurai gem for the crawl! method https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/kimurai/1.3.2/Kimurai/Base#crawl!-class_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `@start_urls = [url]` - plural.
The error is caused by line 131 in the [crawl method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/kimurai/1.3.2/Kimurai%2FBase.crawl!). See the snippet:

```
  spider = self.new

  if start_urls
    ...
  else
    spider.parse
  end
```

Since `start_urls` is not defined it goes to the `else` branch and calls `parse` method that you defined, which requires two arguments but it's called with 0 as the error says.

Comment: I think you are right, Thanks. I edited my answer to reflect that.